# How to fetch GPS coordinates of world's largest cities from WikiData via SPARQL, so that the result set includes Paris?

Tags: gis, sparql, geocoding, wikidata

By searching on Google and SO, I came up with the following SPARQL query for finding world's largest cities for the purpose of rudimentary geocoding:

```sql
SELECT ?city ?cityLabel ?countryLabel ?iso ?population ?gps
WHERE {
  ?city wdt:P31 wd:Q515 . hint:Prior hint:runFirst true .
  ?city wdt:P17 ?country .
  ?country wdt:P297 ?iso .
  ?city wdt:P625 ?gps .
  ?city wdt:P1082 ?population .
  FILTER (?population > 100000) .

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
ORDER BY DESC(?population)
LIMIT 5000
```

https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fcity%20%3FcityLabel%20%3FcountryLabel%20%3Fiso%20%3Fpopulation%20%3Fgps%0AWHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ515%20.%20hint%3APrior%20hint%3ArunFirst%20true%20.%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP17%20%3Fcountry%20.%0A%20%20%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP297%20%3Fiso%20.%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Fgps%20.%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP1082%20%3Fpopulation%20.%0A%20%20FILTER%20(%3Fpopulation%20%3E%20100000)%20.%0A%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0AORDER%20BY%20DESC(%3Fpopulation)%0ALIMIT%205000

For some reason, the result set does not include Paris (France) but includes smaller cities in France. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: can you explain what is missing in the result of your query besides the typo in `?`vs `?gps`

Comment: I just tinkered around, it now returns GPS coordinates, but the result set somehow misses Paris. Probably some filtering is wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> ?city wdt:P31 wd:Q515 .
> ```

This triple pattern excludes [Paris (Q90)](https://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q90), because it’s not an instance of [city (Q515)](https://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q515).

It’s an instance of subclasses of city (Q515), though. For example: [capital city (Q5119)](https://www.wikidata.org/entity/Q5119).

To find all items that are instances of city (Q515) or of a subclass of city (Q515), you can use a [**property path**](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths):

```
wdt:P31/wdt:P279*
```

- P31: [instance of](https://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P31)
- `/`: SequencePath
- P279: [subclass of](https://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/P279)
- `*`: ZeroOrMorePath

---

As a city can be an instance of multiple city subclasses, you might want to make the results distinct, otherwise these cities will appear multiple times in the result:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?cityLabel #etc.
```

Comment: Hmm. I tried `?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515 . hint:Prior hint:runFirst true .`, but this gives `Unknown error: scope=Prior, name=runFirst, value=true, op=PropertyPathNode`

Comment: `?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515 .` seems to work, but works slower. I wonder if I can preserve those hints

Comment: Marked your answer as accepted. Could you please include the final full query (maybe with fixed hints) as part of your answer? e.g. ```SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?cityLabel ?countryLabel ?iso ?population ?gps
WHERE {
    ?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515 .
    ?city wdt:P17 ?country .
    ?city wdt:P1082 ?population .
    ?city wdt:P625 ?gps .
    ?country wdt:P297 ?iso .

    FILTER (?population > 100000) .

    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
ORDER BY DESC(?population)
LIMIT 5000```

Comment: @VadimKantorov: I have no experience with these query hints. You could ask about these in a separate question.